# Check dropbox progress on large files

Tags: java, dropbox-api

How to check dropbox progress on large files?

I'm trying to upload a 1.66 gb file to dropbox using core-api and Java. It is taking an **extremely** long time, (nearly 30 min) and I want to find the progress of the upload.
This is my code for uploading:

```
DbxEntry.File uploadedFile = client.uploadFile("/BIGFILE.zip", 
    DbxWriteMode.add(), finalInputFile.length(), inputStream);
```

Comment: And i control client side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it can be achieved by wrapping the `InputStream` in a 
[`ProgressMonitorInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ProgressMonitorInputStream.html#ProgressMonitorInputStream%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.io.InputStream%29).  But make sure you do not block the Event Dispatch Thread, or it will freeze until completion.

See [How to Use Progress Bars](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html) for details.

Comment: Sorry for my amazing noobiness, can you tell me how exactly i would do that :(