# How to check progress for Upload & Download (Dropbox API Java Core)

Tags: java, httpclient, dropbox, dropbox-api

How to check the progress of an upload that use DropBox API?

The

```
uploadedFile = client.uploadFile("/"+filename,
    DbxWriteMode.add(), f.length(), inputStream);
String fileid = uploadedFile.toString();
```

only return a file which we can check if the file has upload completely.

But I need to check the progress in real time(at least each second or sometime), how to do it?

I found same questions here, but answer uncertain
[Check dropbox progress on large files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20873570/check-dropbox-progress-on-large-files)

Thank a lot! Sorry for my bad english.