# Is there any way to add progress bar for file-upload to dropbox using Java

Tags: java, dropbox-api

I was uploading file to dropbox using java. But the problem is how can I add progress bar to file upload to dropbox. I didn't use java script for it. I didn't get any of this in dropbox API.
my code is.

```
import com.dropbox.core.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Locale;
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DbxException {
    // Get your app key and secret from the Dropbox developers website.
    final String APP_KEY = "INSERT_APP_KEY";
    final String APP_SECRET = "INSERT_APP_SECRET";

    DbxAppInfo appInfo = new DbxAppInfo(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);

    DbxRequestConfig config = new DbxRequestConfig("JavaTutorial/1.0",
        Locale.getDefault().toString());
    DbxWebAuthNoRedirect webAuth = new DbxWebAuthNoRedirect(config, appInfo);

    // Have the user sign in and authorize your app.
    String authorizeUrl = webAuth.start();
    System.out.println("1. Go to: " + authorizeUrl);
    System.out.println("2. Click \"Allow\" (you might have to log in first)");
    System.out.println("3. Copy the authorization code.");
    String code = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).readLine().trim();

    // This will fail if the user enters an invalid authorization code.
    DbxAuthFinish authFinish = webAuth.finish(code);
    String accessToken = authFinish.accessToken;

    DbxClient client = new DbxClient(config, accessToken);

    System.out.println("Linked account: " + client.getAccountInfo().displayName);

    File inputFile = new File("working-draft.txt");
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
    try {
        DbxEntry.File uploadedFile = client.uploadFile("/magnum-opus.txt",
            DbxWriteMode.add(), inputFile.length(), inputStream);
        System.out.println("Uploaded: " + uploadedFile.toString());
    } finally {
        inputStream.close();
    }

    DbxEntry.WithChildren listing = client.getMetadataWithChildren("/");
    System.out.println("Files in the root path:");
    for (DbxEntry child : listing.children) {
        System.out.println("    " + child.name + ": " + child.toString());
    }

    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("magnum-opus.txt");
    try {
        DbxEntry.File downloadedFile = client.getFile("/magnum-opus.txt", null,
            outputStream);
        System.out.println("Metadata: " + downloadedFile.toString());
    } finally {
        outputStream.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe take a look at [`ProgressMonitor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ProgressMonitor.html) or [`ProgressMonitorInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ProgressMonitorInputStream.html)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check dropbox progress on large files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20873570/check-dropbox-progress-on-large-files)

Comment: Hi greg.I was tried with  ProgressMonitorInputStream.But i unable to sync the progress bar with file upload.What should i do.