# Dropbox Java Core API - File upload progression

Tags: java, file-upload, dropbox-api

I'm trying to get the progression of a file upload on Dropbox with the Java Core API.
My actual code is uploading correctly a file but I'm trying to show a progression during the upload time.
I'm writing a command line tool so I can't use swing components as recommanded here: [Check dropbox progress on large files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20873570/check-dropbox-progress-on-large-files).

I'm using the simple method "[uploadFile](http://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v1.7.x/com/dropbox/core/DbxClient.html#uploadFile%28java.lang.String,%20com.dropbox.core.DbxWriteMode,%20long,%20java.io.InputStream%29)".
I already tryed write my own InputSteam subclass but all data are read before uploading. I've also tryed to use the "uploadFile" method [with a DbxStreamWriter](http://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v1.7.x/com/dropbox/core/DbxClient.html#uploadFile%28java.lang.String,%20com.dropbox.core.DbxWriteMode,%20long,%20com.dropbox.core.DbxStreamWriter%29) but the result is the  same:
the file is read then upload starts.

Do you know a way to get the progression of an upload?

Comment: I think what you're doing is the best mechanism available for getting progress. I think the final chunk of the stream should be read as soon as the second-to-last stream has finished uploading. So you should be one chunk (I believe defaults to 4MB in that library) "ahead" in terms of the progress you see. Does that match what you're seeing?

Comment: Well the file I use to test weighs 6.4 Mo and it's entirely read and send in 1 time.